# How to Read the value in a hiddenField from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to read a value in the  hidden field in javascript/Jquery.How can i acheive this ??

Comment: hidden fields are like any other input fields, they are just not visible to to user; all the solutions provided below will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
var value=$('#HidennfieldID').val()
```

value will hold the value of hidden field

Comment: jQuery is clearly ubiquitous, but the user did not indicate they were using that. Edit: Never mind, he did.

Comment: No .He want answer either in javascript or in Jquery

Comment: Uh, yes they did? Just didn't tag it, but it's in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as for a regular field:

```
document.forms[xxx].elements[yyyy].value
```

xxx is the name of the form, or its number. yyyy is the name of the element (or its number).

You can also use `document.getElementById()` to get either the form or the field.

Answer (score 0):

Use the field name or id, e.g.

```
var fVal = $('[name="name"]').val();
var fVal = $('#id').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" value="12345" id="ixd" name='ixd' />

var val = document.getElementById("ixd").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

This an example to read and write value just with pure javascript.

```
<input type="hidden" id="field-id" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('field-id').value = "your value which you want to insert";
    alert(document.getElementById('field-id').value);
</script>
```